# How can i know web view is loading completed

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

i have web view in that i am loading pdf file .

pdf file has 2 mb size so it tacking time. i want to add indicator .

for that how can i know my file is loaded in web view ? ...

Comment: Please be more specific with your question. Do you like to know how to build an indicator / progress bar while downloading 2 mb files or do you just need to know when it is finished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

James P has the right answer (^'ed), but here is the code to show and hide the indicator.

After you've registered with the [UIWebViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)...

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    // Other stuff...
}
```

And then

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    // Other stuff...
}
```

Also you probably want to check for failures and hide the activity indicator there as well...

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    // Other stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[UIWebViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

in particular:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

Comment: I've seen this delegate method get fired at the end of LOADING but long before RENDERING is complete. So watch out.

Comment: Yes that's a good point, I've sometimes added in a small delay before removing my activity indicator to account for this. Unless anyone knows a way to find out when rendering has actually finished?

Comment: I am facing same issue. I want to show an image on the web view after the webview has loaded the pdf page on it. But there is no specific time for rendering the pdf. So I cannot add a delay to show the images. Is there any other way to determine the pdf page has completly rendered on the web view.

Answer (score 0):

first Add the delegate "UIWebViewDelegate", then you can use the below methods.

– webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: 
– webViewDidStartLoad: 
– webViewDidFinishLoad:
– webView:didFailLoadWithError:

Answer (score 0):

You could pull your PDF down using ASIHTTPRequest, which would let you set up a progress bar showing real progress, and then feed it to your UIWebView once it's downloaded.

EDIT: ASIHTTPRequest is a free third-party library that provides a MUCH improved interface to iOS HTTP client functions. LOTS of code samples and instructions here: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Comment: i dont know anything about ASIHTTPRequest can u explain me detail...whats this ? and how can i use this ? plz also attached code for this....i dont have any knowledge abt this things.